# WebHosting server config?

Tags: web-server

hey guys, i dn't know m on right place to ask this question..P.S sry

i want to open/start a new Web Hosting server.. so what kinda config server i may be needing and what exactly stuff are needed.. i want a precise explanation what,how i should proceed and
what hardware n software are required..?? many thanks

**Edited**

- minimun 10,000 users
- space no idea, bandwidth no idea (how much it should be ?)
- yup, its Linux but later on i would like to include windows too
- VPS no idea.. m thinkin' for standard shared hosting (would like to know VPS hosting) so that laterOn can go for VPS hosting
- i have dedicated Lines.
- yes, there should be a control panel
- i'm planing for paid service,but can you explain what services should i provide inreturn of decent pay
- i hv no idea abt redundancy plan
- i do want MySQL database for linux and MSSQl Server for windows

if m goin' for Linux: what OS should i go for eg.CentOs or Fedora or Suse..Suppose laterOn if i want to start windows hosting server also, would i be needing Microsoft .net framework licence for hosting .net WebSites and what OS should i prefer (MS Server2008 ?) and what kinda security i'll be needing, what else factors are there, my budget is around 10,000$ what would you recommend for me ?

Comment: Please specify your needs and what you try to offer. E.g. Windows or Linux, PHP, MySQL, POP/IMAP. A good start is to use any hosting control panel - e.g. http://www.ispconfig.de/ispconfig-3/

Comment: i specified it in regard to the reply of @john T..

Answer (score 1):

There is a multitude of variables that go into web hosting...

- How many users do you plan to host?
- How much space and bandwidth do you plan to offer?
- Do you want to offer Windows hosting, Linux hosting, both? My guess is Linux from your image.
- Do you want to offer VPS hosting or standard shared hosting?
- Do you have a dedicated line(s)? Hosting multiple websites on your home internet is a bad idea. Your ISP will nab you for bandwidth and such.
- Do you want to offer users a control panel? Most decent ones require licensing.
- Free or paid service? If you are making people pay you will probably want more staff to help you for support. You can't expect people to pay money for limited services, especially with the competition out there right now.
- If paid, do you have plans for redundancy?

I could go on forever...

To outline things in general, you will have to answer a few of those questions at least. Horsepower required depends on the quantity of users and the type of hosting, as well as features offered.

I know some free hosting websites that host upwards of 10,000 users on a **single server** (3 Ghz Dual Xeon, 48G memory IIRC). While this is generally not a good idea, it is possible. The reason for this is most of the users' sites don't bring in a lot of traffic, and lots of users are inactive. Hardware required will vary greatly depending on user needs.

For software, the de-facto standard for Linux hosting is Apache. For rapid serving of static content, nginx is popular along side Apache. PHP, Perl, Python and Ruby (rails) are commonly supported for scripting as well. For assisted script installation, software like Fantastico is a popular choice when bundled with cPanel. You will also want to look into an end user database system such as MySQL.

Where I'm going with this is, you're going to have to spend a fair chunk of money somewhere if you want to get anything out of it.

Comment: thankyou very much..i have edited my question, can you please will have a look..